# Replace ControllerLinkBuilder in latest Spring HateOAS

Tags: java, spring, spring-hateoas, hateoas

I have a old project with the following Spring hateoas import dependency:

```
import org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder;
```

Do you know into the latest version how I can replace this import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a class WebMvcLinkBuilder.
It's used like

```
linkTo(OrderController.class).slash(order.getOrderId()).withSelfRel();
```